# Dropdown menu in sidebar

Tags: html, css

This has got me stumped. I have done it before when it worked, and now it won't.

The light background that is behind the navagation bar should also be behind the body of the page.  The footer should not be in it.  There will be more content to go on the page but where the heading is Welcome to The Herb Place should have the light background the same as the nav bar.  Even when I have written `<div id="content-scroll">` in the html the div part comes up red and doesn't even recognise it.

```css
body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image:  url("../photos/background.jpg");
  background-position:  center center;
  background-repeat:  repeat;
  background-size:  100%;
  font-family:   "open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size-size:  medium;
  font-style:   normal;
  line-height:   1.6em;
  margin:   1px auto auto;
  text-align:   left;
  max-width:   1024px;
}
 
#navigation li {
  list-style:    none;
  display:   block;
  float:    left;
  margin:    1em;
}

#navigation li a {
  display:    block;
  text-decoration:   none;
  color:   #006600;
  font-size:    1.6em;
  font-family:   Lucida Console;
  font-style:   italic;
  margin:    0.5em;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
  margin-top:    2px;
  color:   yellow;
}

.rectangle {
  height:    62px;
  position:    relative;
  -moz-box-shadow:   0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  box-shadow:    0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  -webkit-border-radius:  1px;
  -moz-border-radius:   1px;
  border-radius:   1px;
  z-index:    300; /* the stack order: foreground */
  margin:    1em 0;
  background-image:  url("../photos/background2.jpg");
}

#content-scroll  {
  background-image:  url("../photos/background2.jpg");
  max-width:   1024px;
  background-position:  center center;
  background-size:  100%;
}

h1 {
  color:   #669933;
  font-family:   kristen ITC;
  padding:   20px;
  text-align:   center center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The Herb Place</title>
  <link href="html/herb.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
</head>  
<body>
  <header>
    <img id="logo" src="photos/logo.jpg"  alt="My logo">
  
  <!-- the body -->
    <div class="rectangle">
 <!-- the navigation links -->
      <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="Index.html"> HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/about.html"> ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/store.html"> STORE</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/tips.html"> TIPS & HINTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/contact.html"> CONTACT US</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header
  <div id="content-scroll">
  
      <h1> Welcome to The Herb Place</h1>
    
  </div>      
    <div id="footer">
    This website has been created as part of an assignment in an approval course of study for Curtin University and contains copyright<br>
    material not created by the author.  All copyright material used remains copyright of the respective owners and has been used here<br>
    pursuant to Section 40 of the Copyright Act 1968 (Commonwealth of Australia).  No part of this work may be reproduced without<br>
    consent if the original copyright owners.
    </div>  
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle so we can see the code in action

Comment: `</header` should be `</header>`

Comment: can you create a working demo? you can get started here http://jsfiddle.net/n23fqt2t/